# How to keep my id blocked even after I close the application and restart it?

Tags: c++

So I have to do a c++ assignment and I have the following the following instructions:

- Add in the private part:

  ```
  int id; //contains an unique number to identify this object;
          //this number may not be used again!
  ```

  to enable this:
- Add a static private variable to the Class, so you can keep track of
  the number of objects that are created so far.
- Add a static public function to get this number

Note: after you have closed and restarted the application, the used id numbers should still be blocked.

I do not really understand the task and I am not sure how to implement this. Could you help me with this one?

Comment: write it to a file and read it again when starting the program

Comment: What I have done is to have a private static nrOfObjects and public static getNrOfObjects but they just count when an object is created, not really assigning an unique id. Do I have to have also a separate private id or the nrOfObjects I have made a private static is the actual id?

Comment: Please specify what parts of the assignment you have problems with. How to make it persistent over program restart? How to implement unique id's in your program? Something else? Please focus on *one* subject at a time, otherwise this question is too broad and will risk being closed. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And remember that you should always be able to ask your teacher for help and clarifications!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't think the question is too vague. (S)he gave a bulleted list of what his/her assignment was about and said they were having problems with the assignment as a whole. That means they must be having a problem with all the points mentioned.

Comment: @DrakeJohnson One question per question. How to handle unique id's internally in the program is one problem that should be asked in one question, and how to persist the unique id's is another problem that should be asked in a separate question. Besides it's not really clear what problem the OP is actually asking about (how to handle it inside the program, or how to do the persistence, or both which is to broad).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That makes sense; I agree with you now that we're on the same page.

Comment: So I think I found out how to do everything but the part where I need to keep the unique id still blocked even after the application is restarted. So this is my questions: How to keep the id blocked even when the app is restarted? I believe it does not have to be write/read file function.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get something working for you. Let me know in a comment if you have any questions. Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_set>

const char * DATAFILE_NAME = "data.dat"; 

class Object
{
public:
    using id_t = int;

private:
    static constexpr id_t MAX_ID = std::numeric_limits<id_t>::max();

    static id_t objs_created;
    static std::unordered_set<id_t> used_ids;
    id_t m_id;

    // Inits static vars (essentially a load function)
    static void static_init()
    {
        std::ifstream static_vars;
        static_vars.open(DATAFILE_NAME);

        if (static_vars.is_open())
        { // This program has been run before, so load it
            id_t line;

            // Read every line of file into used_ids (1 ID per line)
            while(static_vars >> line)
            {
                used_ids.insert(line);
            }

            // Now, size of used_ids will be the number of objects created
            objs_created = used_ids.size();

            // Close file
            static_vars.close();
        }
        else
        { // File doesn't exist or is corrupted
            std::ofstream mkFile;
            mkFile.open(DATAFILE_NAME); // Make the file
            mkFile.close();

            // Initialize static variables
            // unordered_set does not need to be init'd
            objs_created = 0;
        }
    }

public:
    Object()
    {
        if (used_ids.empty())
        {
            Object::static_init();
        }

        id_t rand_num = 0;
        std::default_random_engine rand_generator(std::time(nullptr));
        // Possible range for random number [0, (max of unsigned long long)]
        std::uniform_int_distribution<id_t> number_range(0, MAX_ID);
        do  // Set a random number over and over again until it is not found in 'used_ids'
        {
            rand_num = number_range(rand_generator);
        } while (used_ids.find(rand_num) != used_ids.end());

        // Set m_id to the random number
        m_id = rand_num;

        // Update static vars
        used_ids.insert(m_id);
        objs_created++;
    }

    // Save function that you can call
    static void save() const
    {
        std::ofstream saveData;
        saveData.open(DATAFILE_NAME);

        if (saveData.is_open())
        {
            // Save every id on its own line
            for (const auto& id : used_ids)
            {
                saveData << id << std::endl;
            }

            saveData.close();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Error! Failed to open datafile!" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    id_t get_id() const { return m_id; }
};

// Init static variables (required for linker)
std::unordered_set<Object::id_t> Object::used_ids;
Object::id_t Object::objs_created = 0;


int main()
{ // Testing the class
    Object obj[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << obj[i].get_id() << std::endl;
    }

    Object::save();
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers unfortunately encourages [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which is bad.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The code has many comments throughout it. Cargo cult is when usually when people don't understand what they're putting in their program. I do understand your concern, though, and I'm open to suggestions on how to make my answer more clear.